# Converting Twisted Code to Asyncio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, twisted, python-asyncio

I have a code which is written in Twisted and I am having trouble with converting it to Asyncio. From my problem the problem is about protocol in Server class. The code which is written with Twisted is this:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
class Client():
    def __init__(self):
        self.something = ""

    def dataReceived(self, packet):
        print(packet)

    def makeConnection(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.server = self.factory

    def connectionLost(self, args):
        print("Connection lost.")

class Server(protocol.ServerFactory):
    protocol = Client

if __name__ == '__main__':
    validPort = []
    S = Server()
    try:
        reactor.listenTCP(44444, S)
        validPort.append(44444)
    except:
        print('Problem about port.')

    if not validPort == []:
        print('Server is running.')
    reactor.run()
```

And this is the code which I converted to Asyncio and doesnt't work (I am not sure the problem is about protocol in Server Class):

```
import asyncio, logging, sys
SERVER_ADDRESS = ('localhost', 44444)

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(name)s: %(message)s',
    stream=sys.stderr,
)
log = logging.getLogger('main')

event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

class Client():
    def __init__(self):
        self.something = ""

    def data_received(self, packet):
        self.log.debug('received {!r}'.format(data))
        print(packet)

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.server = self.factory
        self.log = logging.getLogger(
            'EchoServer_{}_{}'.format(*self.address)
        )
        self.log.debug('connection accepted')

    def connection_lost(self, args):
        if error:
            self.log.error('ERROR: {}'.format(error))
        else:
            self.log.debug('closing')
        super().connection_lost(error)

class Server(asyncio.Protocol):
    protocol = Client

if __name__ == '__main__':
    S = Server()
    factory = event_loop.create_server(S, *SERVER_ADDRESS)
    server = event_loop.run_until_complete(factory)
    log.debug('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*SERVER_ADDRESS))
    try:
        event_loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        log.debug('closing server')
        server.close()
        event_loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
        log.debug('closing event loop')
        event_loop.close()
```

Comment: We are not going to convert it for you. SO is not a coding service. If you have a specific problem please explain it in details.

Comment: The problem is when I convert it to Asyncio I am having problem about protocol in Server class.

Comment: I edited question.

Comment: Now add a proper error description as well.

Comment: I am not getting any error message.

Comment: I converted the code to Asyncio (which is written with Twisted) and there is no error message or something with the code.

Answer (score 0):

In asyncio there is no `ProtocolFactory` abstract interface. Just pass `Client` or `lambda: Client` to `loop.create_server()`

Comment: How can I pass Client to create_server? And where to write pass?

Comment: The first parameter of `loop.create_server()` is a protocol factory. The factory is a callable which is called without arguments and returns a protocol. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-server-protocol for example